# Python Name Exception for name Error Not working, Not able to catch name error

Tags: python, exception, nameerror

Hi guys I am new to python. This is my code. I am able to catch Zero error but not Name error. I am using Python 3.

```
import re 

while True:
  try:
       print("Lets Solve the equation (x/2)/(x-y):")
       print('Please enter 0 to exit')

       x= float(input('Enter the value of x:'))
       y= float(input('Enter teh value of y:'))

       if x==0 or y==0:
          break


       z = (x/2) / (x-y)


  except ZeroDivisionError as e:
       print('There was an error, try again ?') 
       print('You keyed a vlue that caused a division by 0 :') 


  except NameError as e:
       print('There was an error, try again ?') 
       print('you entered a txt where a number was expected') 

  except Exception as e:
       print('There was an error, try again ?') 
       print('Error mesage:',str(e))         


  else:
        print('solving (x/2) / (x-y) for vaule of x=', \
             x, 'and y:', y, 'we get the result:', z)
```

Comment: This is the output i get.

There was an error, try again ?
Error mesage: could not convert string to float: 'ss'
Lets Solve the equation (x/2)/(x-y):
Please enter 0 to exit
Enter the value of x:

Answer (score 0):

Calling `float()` on a string that cannot be converted to a float causes a `ValueError`, not a `NameError`.
Just change your second `except` clause to `except ValueError as e:`.

Comment: Thanks For the reply, any idea how i can catch the error ?

Comment: By changing `NameError` to `TypeError`... or what do you mean by catching?

Comment: @marcng Did this solve your problem? If so, please accept the answer so that future readers can see this solution worked.

Comment: Hi, I did try that but i still get the same error, this is my code

Comment: except TypeError as e:
       print('There was an error, try again ?') 
       print('you entered a txt where a number was expected')

Comment: @marcng I'm sorry. It's a ValueError. I had posted this without testing... Updated the answer now.